# Universial addressing systems

Tags: address

There are some grid-based global addressing systems. NAC (Natural Area Code) is licensed (expensive), but I've seen one from Japan which used more interesting honeycomb-like divisions. I cannot find reference to the latter one, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I was searching for was [GeoHex](http://geohex.net). Practical applications of it may be not so obvious, but it looks really cool.